# Xcode IBOutlet link error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image]

[image]
I made UIView xib. After another class calls that xib,
it's working well. Connecting the outlet until the works.

```
UIView *containerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CommentTextView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
[self.view addSubview:containerView];
```

But if the outlet connected too, an exception occurs:

> 2015-04-22 15:14:50.456 MUZEwithCollectionView[17123:3315297] Unknown class CommentUITableView in Interface Builder file.
>
> 2015-04-22 15:14:50.510 MUZEwithCollectionView[17123:3315297] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key commentTextView.'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1834042d8 0x194bd80e4 0x183403f5c 0x18423d480 0x18332f520 0x1882647a0 0x1882665a8 0x1000d160c 0x187e44c84 0x187e44994 0x18853a2fc 0x18814a148 0x1881663e4 0x188168934 0x187f32158 0x187e79404 0x187e624e0 0x187e78da0 0x187e37fc0 0x187e72898 0x187e71f50 0x187e4518c 0x1880e6324 0x187e436a0 0x1833bc240 0x1833bb4e4 0x1833b9594 0x1832e52d4 0x18cb036fc 0x187eaafac 0x1000e3840 0x195256a08)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Did you bind any ViewController Class to this UIView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `nil`

```
UIView *containerView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CommentTextView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
```

In your case the `owner` is `AccessoryView` not the `self`

From the docs

> owner : The object to assign as the nib’s File's Owner object.

Comment: `MUZEwithCollectionView` why this is unknown class?

Comment: Unfortunately, the same  :(

Comment: It all has to do with your file's owner, check the xib file's owner and make sure it's correct

Answer (score -2):

[image]

I solved this problem by changing the file's owner.